# Separate and display only particular parent term from a taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Is there a module or a way to separate and display only a particular parent term from a taxonomy name in Drupal 7 for the admin, while adding the content.

Consider the home page main menu with vocabulary *Name*.

The home page main menu has the following taxonomy terms.

```
Hello
----Red
----Green
----Blue
Test
----Orange
----Black
----Violet
```

Here in my case I have a content type called Article(for example);

While admin is creating an article, I need to display only the taxonomy term related to *Hello*. Right now it is displaying all the taxonomy terms related to *Hello* and *Test*. Is there a way to separate the parent terms from the same Vocabulary Name.

Comment: Do the Hello and Test terms need to be in the same category?  If they should be used apart from each other, they should probably be separate vocabularies, not the same one.

Comment: there is any way to separate the Hello and test from the same categories or display only hello for the admin using megadesk3000 suggested module.

Comment: You can simply delete the terms from one category and move them to the other.  You'll have to reconfigure all fields that referenced the old terms, though.  Or you can try Jan's solution below.

Comment: Here Hello and Test are the Main menu Menu items.If i move the Hello to separate category, then there is any way to display both the categories in the Main menu.

Comment: How are you displaying them in the menu now?  Just use the same technique to display them in the menu once they are separate.

Comment: I have separated the taxonomy term Hello and test into two separate categories.since The main menu in my site is a taxonomy menu, when i select the Hello item to add an article it is getting added,but the sub menu is added twice in my main menu.Suppose I have selected Red it is getting added twice under the Hello main menu.Any idea.

Comment: This is a separate question and should be addressed as such.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3382/discussion-between-bharathi-and-patrick-kenny)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is, what you searching for: [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree).

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides an expandable tree widget for the Taxonomy Term Reference field in Drupal 7. This widget is intended to serve as a replacement for Drupal's core Taxonomy Term Reference widget, which is a flat list of radio buttons or checkboxes and not necessarily fit for medium to large taxonomy trees.